# Get byte Array from current opened downloaded Word Document .docm from Sharepoint, without save to local drive

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

How can I get the byte array of the opened Word Document (.docm) without saving it to a local drive first.
The document will be opened on a Thin Client without any local drive from SharePoint. When the user want to save the changes, I need to send the byte array to a web-service to process it. (Not back to SharePoint).

```
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim fullFileName As String
filePath = ThisDocument.path
fileName = ThisDocument.Name
fullFileName = filePath + "/" + fileName
```

- the value of filePath is 'http://webiste/application'
- the value of fileName is 'theOpenFileName.docm'
- the value of fullFileName is 'http://webiste/application/theOpenFileName.docm'

How can I get the whole file as a byte array so I can send it to the web-service like this:

```
Dim bytFile() As Byte
Dim http
Dim userName As String
Dim url As String

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
userName = "Me"
 
'--- read file
bytFile = ?????????? 

'--- send the file to the API server
url = "http://localhost/DocWebApi/Post?fileName=" & fileName & "&userName=" & userName
 
http.Open "POST", url, False
http.Send (bytFile)
http.waitForResponse 4000
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try the next approach, please:

```
Sub testByteArray()
  Dim bytFile() As Byte, strDocShare As String
  Dim fileDoc As Integer: fileDoc = FreeFile
  
  strDocShare = Application.GetOpenFilename("Office Documents (*.docm),*.docm", , "Please select document to be processed...")
  If strDocShare = False Then Exit Sub 'If no document has been selected

  Open strDocShare For Binary Access Read As #fileDoc
     ReDim bytFile(0 To LOF(fileDoc) - 1)
     Get #fileDoc, , bytFile
  Close #fileDoc
End Sub
```

If the document will be open, the above code may return an error. A method to determine if a shared document/workbook is open by other user, uses some similar code and catches the error...

Comment: In your case, the file is SAVED on the SharePoint full path. The changes made on the document are not saved, and will not go back to SharePoint. strDocShare needs to be a windows Path and not an URL as I have in my question.

Comment: @klingu: It does not matter! It should work on any path. For a local path, even less 
 restrictions. SharePoint path (only) included in its possibilities. Please, test it and see what it does...

Comment: I got an Error 52. Invalid filename or invalid file numbre: Based on: strDocShare 
 = ThisDocument.FullName

Comment: @klingu: Do you receive the error on that specific line? I cannot imagine that... You maybe receive the error on the line `Open strDocShare For Binary Access Read As #fileDoc`... In such a case, like I told you, **an open document cannot be Read by the method**. Then, do you have the code on the document to be processed? If yes, you must close it and move the code in Normal.dot, or in Excel and close the document to be processed. If the code is in Normal.Dot, it will return the path to Normal.dot...

Comment: @klingu: Please, insert the next line after `strDocShare = ...`: `Debug.Print strDocShare`. What does it return in `Immediate Window` (in VBE - `Ctrl + G`)?

Comment: @klingu: Did you try what I suggested? Should I understand that it did not work in this way, neither?

Comment: The error is indeed on the line     Open strDocShare For Binary Access Read As #fileDoc... and the code is in the document. the strDocShare = the url of the file I work on the document to have the code in SharePoint and try again... brb

Comment: @klingu: Try, please from another document, workbook etc. I adapted the code to offer a browse window to easily select the necessary document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216876/discussion-between-klingu-and-faneduru).