# Get byte Array from current new Word Document, without save to local drive

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

How can I get the byte array of the opened Word Document without saving it to a local drive first.
The document will be created on a Thin Client without any local drive. When the user want to save the document, I need to send the document as a byte array to a web-service to process it.

```
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim fullFileName As String
filePath = ActiveDocument.Path
fileName = ActiveDocument.Name
fullFileName = ActiveDocument.FullName
```

- the value of filePath is ''
- the value of fileName is 'Document1'
- the value of fullFileName is 'Document1'

How can I get the whole file as a byte array so I can send it to the web-service like this:

```
Dim bytFile() As Byte
Dim http
Dim userName As String
Dim url As String

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
userName = "Me"
 
'--- read file
bytFile = ?????????? 

'--- send the file to the API server
url = "http://localhost/DocWebApi/Post?fileName=" & fileName & "&userName=" & userName
 
http.Open "POST", url, False
http.Send (bytFile)
http.waitForResponse 4000
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
To be more clearly => the new document may not be saved on the local machine or a network drive.

Comment: It looks a lot like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62634848/get-byte-array-from-current-opened-downloaded-word-document-docm-from-sharepoin) but the situation is different.

Comment: There's no file until it's been saved somewhere.  The client must have *some* storage?

Comment: Why looks so difficult to keep the code in another Normal.dot/other document/workbook/add-in, save the needed document and use its path to obtain the byte array as I showed you in the other question? I also did this suggestion, but it looks you did not like it...

Comment: @TimWilliams For the users there is a network drive, but not all users do have the same network-drive available. There is no local C-drive or something. If you're saying that it is not possible to get the byte-array from a new document, is it possible to get it from the computer working memory? It has to be exists somewhere...

Comment: @FaneDuru: The discussion was closed when I figured out what the real situation is I have to deal with. The core issue is that I need to send the the file as a byte-array to a web-service and the file may not be saved locally on the user's local drive or network drive.

Comment: I am afraid, your question, as it is, cannot receive an answer... Each application saves a file according to its own "rules", in order to be recognized when opening it. I am also afraid that the file cannot be kept in the memory neither, if it has not previously saved.

Answer (score 0):

To get a byte array the document should be saved. You can use the [SaveAs2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.saveas2) method which saves the specified document with a specified name or format. Some of the arguments for this method correspond to the options in the `Save As dialog box` (see the `File` tab). Basically, you need to save the file on the hard drive anywhere first.

Then you can read the byte array using the [Document.Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.path) property returns the disk path to the document.